# Remove multiple keys from a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series, drop

I have a Pandas series and would like to remove multiple items using a list of keys to be deleted, but this list includes elements which is not a part of the Series keys.

I can do this using the commands below, but believe there must be a more elegant way to achieve this.

```
series1 = pd.Series({'a':8, 'b':7,'c':6, 'd':5})
list1 = ['b', 'c','e','f']

series1.drop(set(series1.keys()).intersection(set(list1)))
```

Result:

```
a    8
d    5
dtype: int64
```

Is there any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can filter with [`Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) (which performs the same set difference without all of the extraction/explicit conversion). In Pandas, inclusive masks tend to be faster and shorter than exclusive masks/dropping rows:

```
series1[series1.index.difference(list1)]
```

```
a    8
d    5
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html?highlight=index%20isin#pandas.Index.isin) to produce a boolean mask and then invert it

```
series1 = series1[~series1.index.isin(list1)]
```

#### Performance

I was curious, so here is a small speed test comparing mine to Henry's solution. Of course, this is a micro-optimisation which is only worth taking into account if you are dealing with tons of data or indexing many times.

**Setup**

```
series1 = pd.Series({'a':8, 'b':7,'c':6, 'd':5})
list1 = ['b', 'c','e','f']

n = 100_000
# repeat series1 n times 
s = series1.repeat(n)

>>> s.shape
(400000,)
```

**Results**

```
>>> %timeit s[~s.index.isin(list1)]

15 ms ± 1.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit s[s.index.difference(list1)]

75.3 ms ± 8.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Yours is faster!! Congrats!!

Comment: @user17242583 Thank you, I guess! ;)